# iPhone View not visible

Tags: iphone

I have the following code in my loadView method and can't understand why I can't see both different colored blocks. I thought the second 'self.view = ' was overlapping the second view so I could only see the green view. However even if I set the views alpha to 0.5 I still don't see the blue block, the green one just becomes more transparent.

Am I missing something really stupid here?

```
- (void)loadView {
CGRect newFrame;
newFrame.origin = CGPointMake(100, 100);
newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(100, 40);
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:newFrame];
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
//myView.alpha = 0.5;
self.view = myView;

CGRect newFrame2;
newFrame2.origin = CGPointMake(100, 200);
newFrame2.size = CGSizeMake(100, 40);
UIView *myView2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:newFrame2];
myView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
//myView2.alpha = 0.5;

self.view = myView2;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `self.view` to `myView`, then just a few lines later reset it to `myView2`. The second assignment replaces the first, just as if you had assigned an integer variable `i = 42` then later `i = 100`.

Look into the `addSubview:` method of UIView.

Comment: Thanks. I tried setting a breakpoint right after the first self.view = myView; but nothing appeared on the screen. I was expecting to see the blue box and then once I past the break, see the view change to green but since I couldn't get that to work I wasn't sure what was going on.

Comment: The display is typically updated once the program gets back to the main loop (which lives inside the framework). Otherwise every operation that changed the display would perform an expensive redraw, even when the very next line is going to require another redraw.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks! I was able to use addSubview: and it works correctly now.   [[self view] addSubview:myView2];

Answer (score 0):

self.view can only hold one view at a time, so in your code:

> self.view = myView;

then

> self.view = myView2;

you are basically replacing "myView" which was assigned to self.view with the new "myView2", so you won't see the first one, and only the second one.

Answer (score 0):

You are simply replacing the view using self.view in subsequent calls.  You are only going to see the second view as it is the last one you are assigning to the current view.

Try using `addSubview:`